# OR operation on integer in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, logical-operators

I need to perform OR operation in xslt 1.0. 
One value is a variable of string type and another is a constant of integer type.
I am using number() function to convert string to integer.

Since, OR performs Bitwise operation on integers, I am comparing the output to the first value, and if they are same only then the image is to be shown.

Below is the xslt code.

```
<xsl: variable name='aflag' select='number((./@flag))' />
<xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="((($aflag or 2) = $aflag)= 'True')">
       <img src='check.gif'></img>
   </xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
```

But the output is always true.

Example: if aflag is 5, it should give false as output. But the output I get is true.

Can somebody please help me. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: "OR performs Bitwise operation on integers": where did you get the idea that in XSLT/XPath the `or` operator performs bitwise comparison on integers? https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#booleans says "An or expression is evaluated by evaluating each operand and converting its value to a boolean as if by a call to the boolean function. The result is true if either value is true and false otherwise. The right operand is not evaluated if the left operand evaluates to true.".

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you gave a clearer statement of what you are trying to achieve: what are the inputs and what is the desired output? Trying to work this out from non-working code isn't easy.